# Getting document value in react.js firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can u guys tell me how to get all `detail` in my document from firestore from my Alarm function?
[image]

here's my Alarm function:

```js
function Alarm() {
  const dummy = useRef();
  const { uid, displayName } = auth.currentUser;
  const alarmRef = firestore.collection("alarm");
  const query = alarmRef.orderBy("detail");
  const [alarm] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: "id" });
  const [alarmValue, setAlarmValue] = useState("00:00:00 AM");

  const sendAlarm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await alarmRef.add({
      detail: alarmValue,
      displayName,
      uid,
    });
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  const stopAlarm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".Sound").pause();
    document.querySelector(".Sound").currentTime = 0;
  };

  const setAlarm = () => {
    var h = document.querySelector(".hours").value;
    var m = document.querySelector(".minutes").value;
    var ap = document.querySelector(".ampm").value;
    var hmap = `${h}:${m}:00 ${ap}`;
    setAlarmValue(hmap);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="sectionInput">
        <div className="alrView">
          {alarm &&
            alarm.map((alr) => (
              <div>
                <AlarmView key={alr.id} alarm={alr} />
              </div>
            ))}
          <span ref={dummy}></span>
        </div>

        <div>
          <select className="hours" onChange={setAlarm}>
            <option>00</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
          </select>
          <select className="minutes" onChange={setAlarm}>
            <option>00</option>
            <option>01</option>
            <option>02</option>
            <option>03</option>
            <option>04</option>
            <option>05</option>
            <option>06</option>
            <option>07</option>
            <option>08</option>
            <option>09</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>26</option>
            <option>27</option>
            <option>28</option>
            <option>29</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>31</option>
            <option>32</option>
            <option>33</option>
            <option>34</option>
            <option>35</option>
            <option>36</option>
            <option>37</option>
            <option>38</option>
            <option>39</option>
            <option>40</option>
            <option>41</option>
            <option>42</option>
            <option>43</option>
            <option>44</option>
            <option>45</option>
            <option>46</option>
            <option>47</option>
            <option>48</option>
            <option>49</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>51</option>
            <option>52</option>
            <option>53</option>
            <option>54</option>
            <option>55</option>
            <option>56</option>
            <option>57</option>
            <option>58</option>
            <option>59</option>
          </select>
          <select className="ampm" onChange={setAlarm}>
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM</option>
          </select>
          <button className="submitTime" type="submit" onClick={sendAlarm}>
            Set Alarm
          </button>
          <button className="stop" onClick={stopAlarm}>
            Stop
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to make my `detail` cannot be submited to firestore if the `detail` duplicate so i need to get all list of my `detail`, here's my web: https://clockreivc.web.app/
and if i `console.log(alarm)` from `const [alarm] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: "id" })` I got this: [image]
and I tried `console.log(alarm.detail)` the error came : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'detail' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are getting a list of alarm documents instead of a list of details, which is a field of said document. Also, I would suggest you don't use a `useCollectionData` hook and instead use a simple SDK call as it could also be generating this issue. So in order to fix it you should do something like this:

```
const alarmRef = firestore.collection("alarm");
const query = alarmRef.orderBy("detail");
//this is the list you want to use
const details = [];
// not sure you want to use this variable but kept it the example just in case
const [alarms] = query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        details.push(doc.data().detail);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry sir, but every time I `log(alarm)`, then the first 1 came in console is undefined then array of my object, I try your code and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` on document, I think it's because my first undefined log(alarm) so your code got error, any idea?

Comment: The problem must be on useCollectionData hook then, can you try not using it and using a simple Firestore SDK call like the one mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), as a test?

Comment: you'r right, can u add ur comment to ur answer?, i'm gonna accept it

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot attached, the *alarm* is the array of objects. You can console the detail by doing this.

```
console.log(alarm[0]?.detail);
```

OR if you want to console all details you can itrate the array

```
 alarm.forEach(item=> console.log(item.detail));
```

and I'll suggest you to rename your variable alarm to alarms to avoid confusion.

Comment: the first one `console.log(alarm[0]?.detail);` got error : `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and the second  `alarm.forEach(item=> console.log(item.detail));` got error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: @Ricky add the `console.log` in the given snippet, just want to know where you are actually trying to console the `alarm`.

Comment: yea, when i console ur code I got that error, and when I `console.log(alarm)` i already sent that on the question (object of alarm {detail, ui, id, displayName})

Comment: can u try my webapp sir? https://clockreivc.web.app/ what I want to do is make sure there's no duplicate alarm, so I need the data of detail then make if statement: there's any data duplicate I block to send to firestore